# Error when importing typeDefs in Apollo Server (Typescript) from a separate file

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I separated the typeDefs into a different file which is written in typescript and later compile to a different file.

I got this error:

> node:internal/errors:490
> ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
> ^

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/pichsophaneatdy/Documents/Lush-To-Do-App/dist/graphql/schema' imported from /Users/pichsophaneatdy/Documents/Lush-To-Do-App/dist/index.js
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
> at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:231:11)
> at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:850:10)
> at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)
> at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:164:28)
> at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
> at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:419:18)
> at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
> at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
> code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
> }

Node.js v19.4.0

TsConfig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2wDo.png)

Server.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYtm9.jpg)

Schema.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNnZc.jpg)

Comment: Are you also using webpack? Note that the generated code refers to `dist/graphql/schema` which is either (a) not getting copied over to `dist/` or (b) is getting combined into a single file. Look inside `dist/` for clues.

Answer (score 0):

I was comparing your code to the Getting Started (Apollo Server v4) on Apollo Docs and your code seems similar enough. I did notice though that in your server.ts file that you're importing a javascript file (./graphql/schema) into a typescript file.

I also took a look at your tsconfig.json file which leads me to this [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-import-javascript-files). I'd basically add the allowJs option and set it to true within tsconfig.json if you want to keep schema file as a javascript file.

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other settings
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the root of problem but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Her Schema is ts not js

Comment: Yup, you're right; I didn't notice the src folder and dist folder counterparts. My bad!